# On which partition can I dual boot linux

Tags: windows-10, lubuntu, dualboot

I would like to install lubuntu alongside windows 10 on my machine. In every tutorial I have seen it is said to extract space for linux from disk C, but I have other partition with much more free space and I am not sure if I can use it instead of C. Is there any difference from which partition will give linux space?

Edit
With answers I have succesfully created free space on disc (image below)
[image]

but now, when I restarts my machine with burned Lubuntu ISO USB, I am choosing to "try lubuntu without instaling" and then from desktop choose to "install lubuntu" I do not see option "Install lubuntu alongside windows". I am confused, so I quit installation, because I am affraid of make any damage to my existing win10 system. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Short answer: No. You can create the free space wherever you like on the disk.

Comment: Can you provide the partition list from Disk Management screenshot? Open Disk Management (diskmgmt.msc) take the screenshot of the bottom half (blue blocks).

Comment: @Biswapriyo image provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only one hard disk then you can create space from any volume of your disk. But if you have a primary partition ssd and a logical volume hard drive then you need to shrink unallocated space from ssd, typically C drive. And if you have ssd and hard disk both are primary, but of different architectures (x86 or x64) then you have to shrink space according the architecture of your lubuntu ISO.